# HTML code to run a local video file working fine on windows but not on android

Tags: android, html, video

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h3>Basic English Lesson Listen & Speak</h3>

<video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="BASIC ENGLISH LESSON 14.mp4" type="video/mp4">
Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>

</body>
</html>
```

The video file is in the same directory folder as my html file.
I need guidance on why its not working on my android 11 OS tablet.

Comment: You should provide proper path for tablet, windows path will not work with direct tablet device.

Comment: @MuhammedIlyas Don't use spaces (in file names) on Android. Try renaming file to `BE_lesson_14.mp4` and also update your HTML. Make sure the MP4 file and the HTML file are together in same folder.

Answer (score 0):

You have to call video.play() in order to play videos in android

Try this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h3>Basic English Lesson Listen & Speak</h3>

<video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="BASIC ENGLISH LESSON 14.mp4">
Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>

</body>
<script>
var video = document.getElementById('video');
video.addEventListener('click',function(){
  video.play();
},false);
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks but still not able to do it